# JQuery Extended Object Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have 3 JQuery plugins which are similar to this

```js
 $(function() {

         var Plugin1/2/3 = {
                fun1:{}
                fun2:{} 
                ...
                init: function()
          {
           o = $.extend({}, this);
                }
         
            }

            $.fn.Plugin1/2/3 = function(){

          return this.each(function(){
                    var obj = Object.create(Plugin1/2/3);
                    obj.init();
                });
         }
         }

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).Plugin1();
   $(document).Plugin2();
   $(document).Plugin3();
});
```

Everywhere i have used variable `o` to extend. What happens is when Plugin3 is created all the objects of above two plugins gets overwritten and all information shown are of the 3rd Plugin.

I am looking for a solution to this as well as some good guides on Jquery Advance plugin creation.

**Pastebin Link:** http://pastebin.com/GJTEEjyt

**Result:**
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: what's this `var Plugin1/2/3 = {`?

Comment: Because here you need a `var` => `var o = $.extend({}, this);`

Comment: I have 3 plugins, Plugin1, Plugin2, Plugin3, so represented like 1/2/3.

Comment: Rahul, LShetty may have been able to figure it out, but you've chopped too much out of the code, leaving the C out of [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited my post with full Jquery pastebin link and result.

Answer (score 3):

That's what happens when you take `var` for granted!

```
init: function() {
    var o = $.extend({}, this);
}
```

And re: jQuery plugin, I have been [using this](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js) for a while now. Take a look.